# Distance between 2 Orthogonal Unit vectors

Tags: vectors, inner-products, orthogonality

Is this true that the Distance between any 2 Orthogonal unit vectors in any inner product space is always equal to $\sqrt2$ ?

Comment: Thank you Sir.......joining MSE is helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider

- $u_1,\quad |u_1|=1\implies u_1\cdot u_1=|u_1|^2=1$
- $u_2,\quad |u_2|=1\implies u_2\cdot u_2=|u_2|^2=1$
- $u_1\cdot u_2=0$

then compute

- $d^2=(u_2-u_1)\cdot(u_2-u_1)$

Comment: Thanks @ gimusi

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal and have norm $1$, what can you say about$$\|u-v\|=\sqrt{\langle u-v,u-v\rangle}?$$

Comment: Thank you @Carlos Santos Sir